# Minimum value of $a\cdot b+2a\cdot c+b\cdot c$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality, vectors, alternative-proof

> find the minimum value of $$S=\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}+2 \vec{a}\cdot\vec{c}+\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}$$ if $|a|=1,|b|=2,|c|=3$

The solution is pretty easy: $$|2\vec{a} +2\vec{c}+\vec{b}|^2\ge 0$$ $$\iff 4+36+4+4S\ge 0$$ $$\iff S\ge -11$$ However if i want to solve this like this it becomes difficult

Let $p,q,r$ be the angles btw the vectors $(a,b),(b,c),(c,a)$ respectively.Then we have to minimise $$S=2\cos p+6\cos q+6\cos r$$ We cannot take $p=q=r=-\pi$ as that would mean all vectors make an angle of $-\pi$ with each other which is insane!

How would i go about solving from this method??

**Update**As Calvin Lin pointed out My first meethod is wrong

Comment: It seems unlikely to yield a solution, in part because there are other constraints that you haven't used. Maybe if you use $ |p| + |q| + |r| \leq 2 \pi$, that might lead somewhere.

Comment: Note that your inequality is wrong. It should be $ |2a + 2c + b | ^2 \geq 2^2 \Leftrightarrow 4 + 36 + 4 + 4S \geq  4 \Leftrightarrow S \geq -10 $. This is achieved at $a = (1,0), b = (2,0), c = (-3,0)$.

Comment: @CalvinLin how did you know it was $2^2$ ?

Comment: Because $2c$ is "big". It has length 6, whereas $2a+b$ has length at most 4.

Comment: Well, you need to find your equality cases, and after playing with it I couldn't get equality to hold. It's just the fact that $|x+y | \geq |x| - |y|$.

Comment: Anyone please tell me why the downvote?Is it beacuse i made an error with my first proof?

Comment: Your first argument only finds an unachievable lower bound. The triangle inequality prevents $2\vec{a}+2\vec{c}+\vec{b}$ from having length less than $2$.

Answer (score 0):

You need the additional constraint that $ p + q + r \leq 2 \pi $ (where we take the angle in the range $ [ 0, \pi ] $).
This is because the angles at the vertex/origin sum up to at most $2 \pi$.

Furthermore, because the coefficients are positive, we will always want to increase $p/q/r$, so the minimum will occur when $ p + q + r = 2 \pi$.

At this point, we can use Lagrange Multipliers to calculate the minimum.

Comment: unfortunately i am not aware of langrange,s multipliers!