# Maximizing angle between three unit vectors

Tags: vectors, 3d

> Find the maximum angle between three equally inclined unit vectors in the 3D space.

### My attempt

Define unit vectors $\hat{a},\hat{b},\hat{c}$ and their components $a_i,b_i,c_i, i\in \{1,2,3\}$

Note that $a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3=c_1b_1+c_2b_2+c_3b_3=a_1c_1+a_2c_2+a_3c_3$

So maximize

$$\arccos(a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3) \text{ or } \arccos(c_1b_1+c_2b_2+c_3b_3) \text{ or } \arccos(a_1c_1+a_2c_2+a_3c_3)$$

under the constraint

$$\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2}=\sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2}=\sqrt{c_1^2+c_2^2+c_3^2}=1$$

I'm not sure what to do next. Any help is appreciated!

---

### Update

WLOG it can be assumed that any one of the vectors is $\hat{i}$ or $\hat{j}$ or $\hat{k}$

This would reduce the number of variables to 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets not complicate it...

Let $p,q,r$ be  unit the vectors indeed $$|p+q+r|^2\ge 0$$

> $$\implies 3+2(p\cdot q+q\cdot r+r\cdot p)\ge 0$$ $$3+6\cos \theta\ge 0$$ Can you end it now?

Comment: Omg I didn't even read that they have equal inclinations lol

Comment: Nice method! I like how the first inequality is trivial! Sometimes we do have to go back to the basics ;^)

Comment: @DatBoi    :)This trick works good but sometimes we have to see if the equality $a+b+c=\vec{0}$ happens as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3929806/minimum-value-of-a-cdot-b2a-cdot-cb-cdot-c)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I just wanted to ask you : do you follow the inequalities tag? I wanted to ask you about something that came up in a chat in the CURED room recently, and it was a point I thought you would know about. If you are ready, you can visit here : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119549/teresa-lisbon-senior-agent-cbi to have this chat with me. Thanks. Also liked this answer.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon yes I do follow the inequality tag will join chat